# Make a new column with a description

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (`df`) which looks like the following:

```
gene               times.x     times.y    times.z
AC113084.1        1            NA          0 
AC124108.15-1     0            5            3
AC154871.1        NA          NA         12
```

What I am trying to do is to make a new column `df$new` where I am going to have names depending the different combinations on the columns times (x.y.z), as below:

```
gene               times.x     times.y    times.z          new
AC113084.1        1            NA          0              located.up
AC124108.15-1     0           5            3             located.down
AC154871.1        NA          NA         12              not.located
```

Could you please give me suggestions how I can make that column to assign these characteristics  (for example I want to print the following):

`located.up` in the column `new` if `times.x>1 & times.y=NA & times.z=0`

`located.down` in the column `new` if `times.x=0 & times.y>1 & times.z>1`

`not.located` in the column `new` if `times.x=NA & times.y=NA & times.z>1`

Comment: And which are the other conditions for located.down and not.located?
Have you tried to do this conditionals to obtain a logic vector and in concordance with this place the name in the new column?

Comment: Your example condition should 've been `DF$times.x >= 1 & is.na(DF$times.y) & DF$times.z == 0`. The output that is a logical vector can be used to subset your `new`: `DF$new[DF$times.x >= 1 & is.na(DF$times.y) & DF$times.z == 0] <- "loc.up"`

Comment: What happens if none of the three conditions is fulfilled?

Comment: Your expected result does not match the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to create a new column based on your rules:

```
ix1 <- df$times.x > 1
iyn <- is.na(df$times.y)
iz0 <- !df$times.z
ix0 <- !df$times.x
iy1 <- df$times.y > 1
iz1 <- df$times.z > 1
ixn <- is.na(df$times.x)

# new vector
newCol <- character(nrow(df))

# replace values in vector
newCol[ix1 & iyn & iz0] <- "located.up"
newCol[ix0 & iy1 & iz1] <- "located.down"
newCol[ixn & iyn & iz1] <- "not.located"

# add to data frame
df$new <- newCol
```

The result:

```
           gene times.x times.y times.z          new
1    AC113084.1       1      NA       0             
2 AC124108.15-1       0       5       3 located.down
3    AC154871.1      NA      NA      12  not.located
```

Note that I followed your rules. Hence, the obtained output for the first row does not match   your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can create nested `ifelse` statements, for example:

```
df$new <- 
  ifelse(df$times.x>1 & is.na(df$times.y) & df$times.z==0, 
         "located.up",
         ifelse(df$times.x==0 & df$times.y>1 & df$times.z>1, 
                "located.down",
                ifelse(is.na(df$times.x) & is.na(df$times.y) & df$times.z>1,
                       "not.located",NA)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just take `gene$new <-` "construction of if and else statements".

Comment: could you please give me an example of how you would do it as I am a rookie in R?

Comment: @Anna In biostar you got something http://www.biostars.org/p/93085/#93087 but you need to explain what are the other conditions as I previously asked

Comment: thank you very much! I have edited my original post with the different conditions...could you please give me an example of how to do it?